# I am using a function to set my app at centre of the screen but it is giving me error 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'center'

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

***It is showing : 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'center'.***
code is here:

```
def setCenter(self): ///this function not working
        '''Function to align the application at centre'''
        qRect=self.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint=QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry.center()
        qRect.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(qRect.topLeft())
```

Also, I have named my application window as `mywindow`, so I am calling this function as `mywindow.setCenter()` in `main()`.

Am I doing it right ?

Comment: Edit your question and add the error you are receiving. As is people viewing your question won't know exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Edited. Please have a look

Comment: Look at tynn's answer, if it doesn't solve your problem try to clarify it to him so he can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDesktopWidget.availableGeometry` is a function. Therefore it doesn't have an attribute of `center`. You need to call the function like `availableGeometry()`. The returned `QRect` has a `center` attribute you can call.

For the geometry of the default screen just use:

```
QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
```

Comment: @Atif Imam are you serious? You need pseudocode to add two brackets after a method?

Comment: oops sorry . Didn't watch the last line . :/ As you can see last line code was added after my comment